# Rails&wicked_pdfによるPDF出力について

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

現在、以下の環境でPDFを帳票出力しています。

---

CentOS6.6 
Rails 4.0.2 
ruby 2.1.0 
wkhtmltox-0.12.2.1 
wicked_pdf 0.11.0

---

この環境でHTMLのテーブルで帳票レイアウトし、PDFを出力し、テーブルがページをまたがると、またがった方のページの帳票の 
レイアウトが崩れてしまいます。

具体的には、テーブルのヘッダーが再度表示されその次に表示するはずの行をさらに上に印字してしまっているような表示です。

例） 
１ページ目 
id　　 | name　　　　| age　 　 | 
　　1　|　　　tanaka　|　　　30　| 
　　2　|　　　aikawa　|　　　48　| 
　　3　|　　　nomura　|　　　29　| 
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ 
２ページ目 
id　32　| name　noda　| age　32　| 
　　33　|　　　tanabe　|　　　18　| 
　　34　|　　　tamura　|　　　25　|

テーブルのヘッダーが再度表示される事自体は非常に喜ばしい事なんですが、 
どうしても上記のような表示になるのならヘッダーは始めの一つだけで構わないと考えております。

なにか、良い回避方法などありますでしょうか？